# Excel: Create all Possible Combinations of Column A and (individually) an unlimited number of Columns B thru "x"

Tags: excel, combinations

I have data in Column A and need the results of all combinations with each of the data in Columns B, C, D, etc...

So I don't need the combinations of all the columns against each other, I need AB, AC, AD, AE, etc...

Easier for my purposes to have the results combined per cell with a space between the now combined data

So for example

```
Blue   One
Red    Two
Yellow Three
```

Would become

```
Blue One
Blue Two
etc
```

Like to be able to designate the ordering as well of the combinations, for example, all possibilites for each of Columns B, C, D, etc... where the Column A cell data is appended instead of proceeding

Comment: This will take vba.  Formulas do not open ended column counts.

Answer (score 1):

This uses array as much as possible thus limiting the number of time the worksheet is accessed

```
Sub mygrouping()
    With Worksheets("Sheet6") ' change to your sheet
        Dim rngA As Variant
        rngA = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value

        Dim rngOthers As Variant
        ReDim rngOthers(1 To Application.CountA(.Range("B1", .Cells(1040000, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)))) As Variant
        Dim j As Long, k As Long, i As Long
        k = 1
        For j = 2 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            rngintm = .Range(.Cells(1, j), .Cells(.Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp)).Value
            For i = 1 To UBound(rngintm, 1)
                If rngintm(i, 1) <> "" Then
                    rngOthers(k) = rngintm(i, 1)
                    k = k + 1
                End If
            Next i
        Next j
        Dim outarr() As Variant
        ReDim outarr(1 To UBound(rngA, 1) * UBound(rngOthers), 1 To 1)
        k = 1
        For i = 1 To UBound(rngA, 1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(rngOthers)
                outarr(k, 1) = rngA(i, 1) & rngOthers(j)
                k = k + 1
            Next j
        Next i


        'Outputs to another sheet change to your sheet name and desired location
        Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(outarr, 1), 1).Value = outarr

    End With
End Sub
```